# Powershell script with a background job inside called from c#

Tags: c#, powershell, asynchronous

I call a Powershell script from a `c#` program, getting back an collection of `PSObjects` as a result of `pipeline.Invoke()`. As a part of the PS script, an email is sent using Net.Mail.SmtpClient. However, sending an email takes some time, so I moved the email sending code into a script block that is executed using `Start-Jon -ScriptBlock`... And here the problem started: email is not sent. When I execute a script from a command line, it sends an email.

What can be the reason?

Comment: Any output or error messages ?

Comment: Not really. `pipeline` return no errors, script works (in a sense that it returns processed data back to the c# program. Just email is not sent.

Comment: Have you tried running a "dumber" script i.e. one that just writes the arguments/parameters you are passing to a file instead of emailing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, after adding `Wait-Job` to the code (making it synchronous) it worked again. I think that I got it. 
I was calling `runspace.Close()` at the end of my code that terminated the host so the Powershell background job had no chance to be executed. So I looking in the wrong place, unfortunately.